# ¿Por qué input() me devuelve None?

Tags: python, input

He estado leyendo acerca de los posibles errores para que me retorna None, pero son de casos que no se ven en mi código:

```
def remover_enesimo(s, n):
  remove = print(s.replace(s[n],""))
  return remove
texto = input("ingresa tu texto ")
numero = int(input("ingresa el numero "))
print(remover_enesimo(texto,numero))
```

Comment: El `print()` siempre retorna `None`, me da la impresión que lo que buscas es `return s.replace(s[n],"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenida,

Como perfectamente remarcan @Candid Moe y @Patricio Moracho, la función *print* devuelve **None** de ahí que cuando asignas el valor de la salida de la función *print* a una variable, remove en tu caso, el resultado es **None** (documentación de *print* https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

**Solución aparente:**

Digo *aparente* porque es mi interpretación de lo que intentas hacer:

```
def remover_enesimo(s, n):
    remove = s.replace(s[n],"")
    return remove
texto = input("ingresa tu texto ")
numero = int(input("ingresa el numero "))
print(remover_enesimo(texto,numero))
```

**Apunte importante:**

En este tipo de scripts/apps donde se pide interacción con el usuario es recomendable revisar que el valor de entrada (índice a borrar) no excede el máximo valor de índice posible de string introducido para así evitar un error del tipo:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Quedando algo, por ejemplo, parecido a esto:

```
def remover_enesimo(s, n):
    if n >= len(s):
        return 'El indice introducido excede el valor maximo posible que es %d para %s' % (len(s)-1, s)
    remove = s.replace(s[n],"")
    return remove
texto = input("ingresa tu texto ")
numero = int(input("ingresa el numero "))
print(remover_enesimo(texto,numero))
```

Así podemos obtener esto:

```
ingresa tu texto >? texto
ingresa el numero >? 5
El indice introducido excede el valor maximo posible que es 4 para texto
```

Donde podemos ver que la palabra texto contiene 5 letras pero como Python es zero-based-index (es decir primer elemento de un array es el elemento 0) el índice máximo posible es **4** correspondiente con la o de la palabra text**o**

Saludos